# Can I make Eclipse link against platform specific libraries based on the platform?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

For some reason I've begun to actually like the CDT in Eclipse -- it appears Eclipse is the only IDE I could find that would allow me to set up the UI in any reasonable manner (personal taste applied). Since modern C++ now has `__has_include`, I'm even able to write code that is reasonable able to discriminate based on the features of a platform (rather than the platform itself). The only thing missing is linking libraries.

Besides using configuration profiles (the debug/release stuff), is there any way that I can make Eclipse link against certain libraries based on the platform. Creating profiles that are disabled on certain platforms is acceptable.

Bonus points if I can link against libraries based on which libraries exist on the system.

Comment: I do this by writing my own makefile. In the makefile I check `$(shell uname)` against different values to detect the platform.

Comment: That's not exactly a reliably method unfortunately. I've been doing similar tricks for years and I've never been able to do it in a way that I was satisfied with.